# Try changing name switch my profile picture

Tags: bug, profile-page, display-names

I cannot change my display name since it hasn't been 30 days but since mine doesn't fit anymore, I tried again to see the days counter.

I went on that page :

> [image]

Tried changing the name and my profile picture changed :

> [image]

Comment: Well you *must* be a different person if you changed your username, right? :P

Comment: I think it's some old code that has the Gravatar usage coded-in specifically. You could have changed your email, but due to an error that change wouldn't have been saved to the database. The standard avatar system wouldn't display the updated Gravatar, so this page's view or whatever wasn't using it.